# Multiple Listeners on firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a live scoring server that updates scores in firebase when games are created. Currently, the node server has a listener with the code below specifically referencing the type of node with firebase.

```
ref.orderByChild("league").equalTo('NBA').on("value", function(snapshot) {
refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
  nbafile.nbaUpdate(snapshot.val());

}, 5000);

 }, function(errorObject) {});
};
```

As it stands now when a game is created in firebase a timer is set to update the game every 5 seconds and stops updating after the game status is closed.

HERE IS THE PROBLEM:

If I try and add an additional listener for another sport such as NCAAB it is either never activated or they are both called but the timer doesn't stop.

```
ref.orderByChild("league").equalTo('NCAAB').on("value", function(snapshot) {
refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
  cbbfile.cbbUpdate(snapshot.val());
}, 5000);
}, function(errorObject) {});
```

}

Whichever function is called first gets precedent, and the other sport doesn't fire.

Below is a complete piece of code along with an if statement the games are pointing go.

```
    const startUpdate = function(db, ref) {

  db = admin.database();
  exports.db = db;
  ref = db.ref('game');
  exports.ref = ref;
  console.log('-----------------------------------');
  ref.orderByChild("league").equalTo('NBA').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
      nbafile.nbaUpdate(snapshot.val());

    }, 5000);

  }, function(errorObject) {});

};

const startUpdate2 = function(db, ref) {

  db = admin.database();
  exports.db = db
  ref = db.ref('game');
  exports.ref = ref;
  console.log('-----------------------------------');
  ref.orderByChild("league").equalTo('NCAAB').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
      cbbfile.cbbUpdate(snapshot.val());
    }, 5000);

  }, function(errorObject) {});
}
```

nbaupdate.js

```
    let nbaUpdate = function(games) {
  console.log("Professional Basketball");
  if (games === null) {
    console.log('Games object empty');
    return;
  }
  for (var id in games) {
    if (games[id].league === 'NCAAB');
    if (ts >= games[id].scheduledTimeUnix);
    if ((games[id].status == 'complete') || (games[id].status == 'closed')) {
      sports.clearTimer();
      console.log(games[id].status)
    } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was not working was that I had the same clearTimer() function on each lister. So the interval was clearing on both listeners.